# IMO 2006, A4 Problem, Idea behind the proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, fractions, sum-of-squares-method

**IMO 2006, Problem A4, page 13:**

> Prove the inequality:
>   $$
>    \sum_{i<j} \frac{a_{i}a_{j}}{a_{i}+ a_{j}} \le 
>    \frac{n}{2(a_{1} + a_{2} + \cdots + a_{n}) }\sum_{i<j}a_{i}a_{j}
> $$
>   for positive real numbers $a_{1}$, $a_{2}$, ..., $a_{n}$.

**Solution** (when I try to hide it, I've got the formlas broken - sorry)

Let $S = \sum\limits_{i} a_{i}$. Denote by $L$ and $R$ the expressions on the
left and right hand side of the proposed inequality. We transform $L$
and $R$ using the identity:
$$
 \sum_{i < j} (a_{i} + a_{j}) = (n-1) \sum_{i}a_{i}.
$$
And thus:
$$
  L = \sum\limits_{i<j} \frac{a_{i}a_{j}}{a_{i} + a_{j}} = \frac{n-1}{4} S - 
  \frac{1}{4}\sum_{i < j} \frac{ (a_{i} - a_{j})^2}{a_{i} + a_{j}}.
$$
To represent $R$ we express the sum $\sum\limits_{i<j}a_{i}a_{j}$ in two ways:
$$
 \sum_{i<j} a_{i}a_{j} = \frac{1}{2}\left(S^2 - \sum_{i} a_{i}^2\right)
$$
$$
   \sum_{i<j}a_{i}a_{j} = \frac{n-1}{2} \sum_{i}a_{i}^2 
- \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i<j}(a_{i} - a_{j})^2.
$$
Multiplying the first of these equalities by n-1 and adding the 
second one we obtain
$$
  n\sum_{i<j}a_{i}a_{j} = \frac{n-1}{2} S^2 - 
  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i<j}(a_{i} - a_{j})^2
$$
Hence
$$
  R = \frac{n}{2S} \sum_{i<j}a_{i}a_{j} = 
\frac{n-1}{4}S - \frac{1}{4}\sum_{i<j}\frac{(a_{i} - a_{j})^2}{S}
$$
Now compare the last two equalities. Since $S \ge a_{i} + a_{j}$ 
for any $i<j$, the claim $L \ge R$ results.

**My question:** what is the idea behind this proof, and how to think it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind this proof: try to rewrite our inequality in the following form: $$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(a_i-a_j)^2S_{ij}\geq0$$ and to hope that $S_{ij}\geq0$.

This method names SOS (Sum Of Squares). It's a very useful method.

See here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/sos/info
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sos

Comment: What do you mean by $S_{ij}$?

Comment: @Simeon Y In our case $S_{ij}=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_k}{a_i+a_j}-1>0$

Comment: Oh, thank you! That is very helpful comment!

Comment: @Simeon Y You are welcome!